# Where can I find a pre-compiled Markdown# dll?

Tags: .net, open-source, markdown, markdownsharp

I'd like to use [Markdown#](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) in a project I'm working on (Not a .Net project, but I have the ability to instantiate .Net class libraries and use them natively). Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a pre-compiled Markdown# DLL.

I'd really rather not install Visual Studio just for the purpose of compiling the project.

Are there DLL download links somewhere that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need Visual Studio. Just run `msbuild` which comes with the .NET Framework on the solution file.

Open up a command prompt, switch to the MarkdownSharp directory, and run `msbuild`:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe"
```

Comment: ".\MarkdownSharp.sln(2): Solution file error MSB5014: File format version is not recognized.  MSBuild can only read solution files between versions 7.0 and 9.0, inclusive."

Comment: @Adam: You'll have to run the newer msbuild. I just copy pasted a sample path. Replace the version number with 3.5.